# State does not change on Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

Here is my component code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Text, SvgContainer, Svg, Flex } from "../lib/styles";
import Modal from "./Modal";

const Credits = () => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  
  const openModal = () => {
    alert("state should change")
    setModal(true);
    alert("after");

  };
  
  const closeModal = () => {
    setModal(false);
  };

  return (
    <Flex>
      <Text $SubHeader>Crafted By Michele Staffiere 2023</Text>
      
      <SvgContainer onClick={()=>{openModal()}}>
        <Svg src="/assets/question-mark.svg" />
      </SvgContainer>
      
      <Modal isOpen={modal} Close={closeModal} Open={openModal} />
    </Flex>
  );
};

export default Credits;
```

I'm trying to toggle the state of my modal with this element:

```
<SvgContainer onClick={()=>{openModal()}}>
    <Svg src="/assets/question-mark.svg" />
</SvgContainer>
```

The issue is that the `openModal()` function isn't updating my state at all – it remains false. My alerts trigger both before and after the `setModal(true)` so why is my state remaining as `false` in my dev tools? This is resulting in my modal never actually popping up on page.

When I go into my dev tools and manually set the state to `true`, my modal opens fine and the close modal function works fine as well when I click outside the modal area.

Why is my:

```
const openModal = () => {
  alert("state should change")
  setModal(true);
  alert("after");
};
```

not updating the state at all?

Comment: Could you create a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  It seems strange that the state setter is being invoked but state is not updating.

Comment: Exactly. An MRE is needed. The state setter seems to be executing perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the "set state function" is an asynchronous function.  When your code first hits the call, it puts the call onto JavaScript's "asynch queue" to be executed later, then JS continues running....executing your second `alert()` before the asynchronous code gets executed.

This is the way that JavaScript works.

I strongly encourage all of my friends (and make it a requirement of all of my coworkers) to watch the video [JavaScript: Understanding the Weird Parts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bv_5Zv5c-Ts&t=1s) multiple times.  Especially the parts about Synchronous and Asynchronous code execution (time links are in the video description).

If this were me, I would add `console.log("modal is:", modal);` immediately before the `return()` that returns the JSX for your component.  That will let you see the value every single time the component renders.